# How to redirect custom ajax form to external url

Tags: 8, forms, ajax, redirection

When setting the form with ajax handler like this

```
  public function buildForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    //...

    $form['actions']['submit'] = array(
      //...
      '#ajax' => [
        'wrapper' => 'custom_form_wrapper',
        'callback' => '::ajaxCallback',
      ],      
    );
  }
```

and trying to set the redirect on `submitForm`

```
  public function submitForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    $url = 'https://example.com';
    $form_state->setResponse(new \Drupal\Core\Routing\TrustedRedirectResponse($url, 302));
  }
```

nothing happens and no error message appears but the form seems like it has finished processing.

When the ajax part is taken out the action:submit array the form redirects properly on submit.  What should be done differently ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't return a redirect response, because the ajax script in the browser expects a json array with jquery commands, so you need to return a [RedirectCommand](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Ajax%21RedirectCommand.php/class/RedirectCommand/8.5.x) from the ajax callback:

```
  public function ajaxCallback(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    $response = new AjaxResponse();

    $command = new RedirectCommand('https://example.com');

    return $response->addCommand($command);
  }
```

which then assigns window.location to redirect client-side.